# Does the SF1 mobile app support the beforeUnload event?

Tags: javascript, salesforce1-app, mobile

I have a VF page that is running javascript and should throw a before unload alert message if the user tries to navigate before saving. This works in all browsers except on the SF1 app which nothing is shown.

Is beforeUnload just not supported in the SF1 app?

Comment: If I remember right, you can't do anything that's modal, like confirming navigation, alert boxes, etc. Unfortunately, I don't have time to experiment with it right now.

Comment: I've gotten alert boxes to work (that's the only way I know how to debug on the app) but can't figure out beforeunload